# Linear regression t-value missing in r.series QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using QGIS 3.22.15, but I noticed that in the **GRASS r.series** tool there is no **tvalue** function (see image) as described instead in the manual here https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.series.html.

[image]

How can I get it?

Comment: This was discussed on GRASS Gitter https://gitter.im/grassgis/community